# Can't create calendar on iPhone but can on the simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, calendar

I would like to create a custom calendar in which to create all the app related events. I would like to this calendar to be of `EKSourceType` `Local`.

I can create such a calendar on the simulator and add events to it but when I try to add it on my iPhone it does't work.

My code to create the calendar:

```
    if (eventManager.eventStore?.calendarWithIdentifier(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("calendar_identifier") as? String) == nil){
        //The calendar doesn't exist, create a new one with the correct properties.
        calendar = EKCalendar(forEntityType: EKEntityTypeEvent, eventStore: eventManager.eventStore)
        calendar.title = "My Calendar"
        calendar.CGColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.62, blue: 0.10, alpha: 1).CGColor
        // Find the proper source type value.
        var localSource:EKSource? = nil

        if let eventStore = eventManager.eventStore{
        //get the correct source for the calendar
            for source in eventStore.sources() as [EKSource] {
                println("eventStore.source - \(source)")
                switch (source.sourceType.value){
                /*
                case (EKSourceTypeSubscribed.value):
                  localSource = source
                */
                case (EKSourceTypeLocal.value):
                  localSource = source
                default:
                  break
                }
            }
            calendar.source = localSource
            }
            //save the newly created calendar
            eventManager.eventStore!.saveCalendar(calendar, commit: true, error: &error)
            //check for any errors.
            if(error == nil){
                //no errors were encountered save identifier
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(calendar.calendarIdentifier, forKey: "calendar_identifier")
                    println("Making calendar")
            }else{
                    println("error in making calendar - \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                    return
            }
       }
```

I first check if a calendar identifier exists in the NSUserDefaults. I then create the new calendar and assign the local source to it once it is found. Then I save the calendar (which works and returns true.) No errors are returned and when I print the source it gives:

```
EKSource <0x1700dad30> {UUID = BD42B102-A185-4A93-9114-737001A4C408; type = Local; title = Default; externalID = (null)}
```

What am I doing wrong here, or what is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug/strange behavior with iCloud.

That happens if you have iCloud activated, but you have disabled to sync the Reminders. [This Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19430924/unable-to-create-local-ekcalendar-reminders-if-icloud-is-set-to-not-sync-remin) had the same problem(but couldn't resolve it).

Try to enable Reminder-sync.